# curl command for proxy and webpage login

Tags: bash, curl

I want to test my curl script to login and download a csv file. The challenge for me i need to use 2 username and password
1. for bypassing the proxy
2. login to the webpage and download the csv file.

I have used the following  curl script with no luck

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -o test.csv -vk -x https://url:8000 --proxy-user username1:password1 -L https://url.../ti/v1/attackerdb&format=csv -u username2:password2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `https://url.../ti/v1/attackerdb&format=csv` is not quoted in the example, and that's a problem because the `&` has a special meaning in the shell. Put single or double quotes around it, like this:

```
curl -o test.csv -vk -x https://url:8000 --proxy-user username1:password1 -L 'https://url.../ti/v1/attackerdb&format=csv' -u username2:password2
```

Watch out for other arguments too that might need to be quoted. Quite possibly the passwords, for example.

Other than that, it seems the script should work.

Comment: THanks a lot janos.. that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have `$` as part of username or password (or for that matter other shell specific charcters), then to avoid shell interpretation, surround with single quotes.

For example:

```
--proxy-user 'username1:password1'
```

and

```
-u 'username2:password2'
```

I would also put the actual url at the end since typical syntax is options first followed by url.